# DirectX 3D rotate eyePt around lookAt

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, directx-9

I'm really stuggling with the maths i need for this maths has never been my strong point once you get into Calculus and Geometry.

So how do i rotate a vector3 around another vector3

```
D3DXVECTOR3 lookAt = this->cam->getLookAt();
D3DXVECTOR3 eyePt = this->cam->getEyePt();
```

I need to rotate `lookAt` around `eyePt` how do I do this I know I need a Matrix but what I'm supposed to fill it with and how I do the rotation in it I just don't understand.

So if some one could provide code with explanations of the steps used to do it would really help

Another note is that i only want to translate on X,Z axis as i'm rotation around Y axis so here is an image of what im trying to do
[image: rotation around Y axis (top down view)]

Comment: Do you know how to multiply a matrix by a vector to get a new vector?

Comment: don't you just use the normal `*` operator.

Comment: Think about it as: a translation by -eyePt, so that the point you're rotating around is at (0,0,0), followed by a rotation (easy now you're at the origin), followed by a translation back by +eyePt to put the point back where you want it. These can all be combined into one matrix of course.

Comment: you have said that but how do i put a Vector3(xyz) into a matrix is it `1x1, 2x1, 3x1` or is it `1x1, 1x2, 1x3` this is what i dont understand how do i set up values in a matrix? and how do i then use the matrix this is what i dont understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the unit vector eyePt, which will be the axis of rotations. (I presume it's a unit vector; if not, I can show you how to turn it into a unit vector.) Let's call it **E**:

```
    Ex
E = Ey
    Ez
```

(This is the vector (E<sub>x</sub>, E<sub>y</sub>, E<sub>z</sub>), but it's hard to do mathematical notation here.)

Now construct three matrices. The identity matrix **I**:

```
    1 0 0
I = 0 1 0
    0 0 1
```

the tensor product of **E** and **E**, which we'll call **T**:

```
      0 -Ez  Ey
T =  Ez   0 -Ex
    -Ey  Ex   0
```

and the cross-product matrix of **E**, which we'll call **P**:

```
    ExEx ExEy ExEz
P = ExEy EyEy EyEz
    ExEz EyEz EzEz
```

Now choose an angle of rotation, theta (in radians). The rotation matrix will be:

**R** = cos(theta)**I** + (1-cos(theta))**T** + sin(theta)**P**

Now to rotate the vector v (which in this case is `lookAt`), just multiply **R** by it:

v<sub>after</sub> = **R**v<sub>before</sub>

Comment: Thanks only one question what is theta?

Comment: Thanks so much that makes more sence than anything else i have read about it :)

Comment: Oh wait sorry i do need you to show me how to convert a vector into a unit vector

Comment: The other problem i have is the Matrix i have access to are 4x4 would that make a difference?

Comment: The only Matrix class you have is 4x4? Are you sure your vectors have only 3 elements, not 4?

Comment: positive the Vector3 only has (x,y,z)

Comment: @MartinBarker: Is there a `Vector4` you can use? If need be you can do the calculations without the 4x4 Matrix, but it would be tiresome.